# Overriding ApplicationRecord initialize, bad idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, overriding

I am creating a *foo* obeject like this:

```
@foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
@foo.bar = Bar.where(name: "baz").first_or_create
```

But there are other objects that I will need to do this as well. So, I thought of overriding the *Foo* initialize method to do something like this:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize(*args, BarName)
    @foo = super
    @foo.bar = Bar.where(name: BarName).first_or_create
  end
end
```

and call it like this:

```
@foo = Foo.new(foo_params, "baz")
```

But Foo is an ApplicationRecord and it seems that it's not recommended to override the ApplicationRecord initialize method.

So how could I do this? Any other ideas? Would this initialize overriding thing work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [active record callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for that. However you won't be able to to specify bar_name and will somehow need to find it dynamically from Foo attributes.

If that option works you. Add to your model something like the the following code.

```
after_initialize :set_bar

# some other code

def set_bar
  name = # dynamicly_find_name
  self.bar = Bar.where(name: name).first_or_create
end
```

In case you really need to specify `bar_name`, I would suggest to create a method for it.

`Foo.new(params).with_bar`

```
def with_bar(bar_name)
  self.bar = Bar.where(name: BarName).first_or_create
end
```

Comment: Note that `with_bar` will return `self.bar` after execution. If you want to simply set `bar` and then return `self` (i.e. the object), I recommend using tap:
`self.tap { |obj| obj.bar = Bar.where(name: bar_name).first_or_create }`. This allows you to continue chaining methods.

Comment: Note that `after_initialize` is called not only when you initalize a new record in your code but also every time the record is loaded from the database. See [docs on after_find and after_initialize](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find)

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of the after_initialize callback and use transients if necessary:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :custom_initialization

  attr_accessor :barname

  def custom_initialization()
    self.bar = Bar.where(name: self.barname).first_or_create
  end
end
```

The application records own initialisation should take care of setting `barname` providing it is in the params

Comment: I would only suggest you use `attr_accessor` for `barname`

Comment: true ... that would be better .. I shall modify the answer accordingly. Ty @NikitaMisharin for the input.