# Rails undefined method in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the cassandra gem.
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/ruby-driver/3.0/features/

In my model I'm doing the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  require 'cassandra'

  def initialize
    @cluster = Cassandra.cluster
  end

  def session
    @cluster.connect('capsula')
  end

  def total_users
    result = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    result.size
  end

end
```

But when I call the `total_users method` the error is shown:

> undefined method `connect' for nil:NilClass

```
def session
  @cluster.connect('capsula')
end
```

I wanted to save the connection on a variable so it would not be necessary to make a new connection for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `@cluster` is nil, so it hasn't been properly initialized.

It [isn't a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165520/overriding-applicationrecord-initialize-bad-idea) to define `initialize` for Rails models. You could use [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) instead.

If I understand it correctly, the session doesn't depend on the User, and could be defined for `User` class instead of `User` instances :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  require 'cassandra'

  class << self
    def cassandra_session
      @session ||= Cassandra.cluster.connect('capsula')
    end
  end

  def total_users
    result = User.cassandra_session.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    result.size
  end
end
```

Using `@session ||=` means that `@session` will be initialized once and kept in cache afterwards :

```
@x ||= 1
@x ||= 2
@x ||= not_even_called
puts @x
#=> 1
```