# Rails 5 - RSpec with FactoryGirl giving error wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

This is the first time I am writing test cases on a rails project which is using RSpec and FactoryGirl

When I run the test case i get the following error

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

I have gone through other posts at stack over flow and they are not much helpful in my case.

**What I have tried**

I am writing a test case on a Model which is called `ImportFeed` and it looks something like as following

```
class ImportFeed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :staffroom
  belongs_to :user,  optional: true   # We don't have to have a user

  validates_presence_of  :url, :feed_type
  validates :enabled,     presence: true, allow_blank: true

  def initialize(params)
    super(params)
    self.enabled = false if self.enabled.blank?
    self.default_radius = DEFAULT_RADIUS  if self.default_radius.blank?
    self.default_days = DAYS_DEFAULT if self.default_days.blank?
  end
end
```

This is what my test case looks like

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe JobImporters::JoraJobImporter, '.run' do

  it 'should create an instance of ImportFeed' do
    feed = ImportFeed::new FactoryGirl.create(:import_feed, :import1)
    expect(feed).to be_a ImportFeed
  end
end
```

This is the factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :import_feed do

    trait :import1 do
      enabled true
      feed_type 'example'
      staffroom_id 7526
      url Faker::Internet::url
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this I get the error mentioned at the beginning of this question,

If I pass the data to the test case without FactoryGirl then my test case works and passes for example if I replace

```
feed = ImportFeed::new FactoryGirl.create(:import_feed, :import1)
```

with

```
feed = ImportFeed::new enabled: true, staffroom_id: 7526, feed_type: 'example', url: Faker::Internet::url
```

the test case passes.

I will really appreciate if someone can point to me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: `ActiveRecord#new` accepts hash only, why did you pass an object to it? I'm wondering why didn't you get `ArgumentError` exception :) (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb#L27)

Comment: You are right, i should have picked that up, I am also wondering even if i dont pass it to ActiveRecord and just do `data = FactoryGirl.create(:import_feed, : import1)` I still get the same error, shouldn't it at least return be the object this way?

Comment: Hi @Baig, I think you're overriding `initialize` method. Could you show me how did you override?

Comment: Sure, could you please elaborate what details are you referring to and I will add that to the question?

Comment: I meant `initialize` method

Comment: I am not overriding initialize anywhere

Comment: I saw `def initialize(params)` in your `ImportFeed` model ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169738/discussion-between-baig-and-fongfan999).

Comment: I have updated the question by adding more details about def initialize(params)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're overriding `initialize` method, so you got unexpected exception.

> Don't override initialize on ActiveRecord objects
>   ActiveRecord::Base doesn't always use new to create objects, so initialize might not be called. [[link]](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html)

In order to solve your problem, you should set your attributes in callback instead

```
class ImportFeed < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  after_initialize :set_my_attributes

  private

  def set_my_attributes
    self.enabled = false if self.enabled.blank?
    self.default_radius = DEFAULT_RADIUS  if self.default_radius.blank?
    self.default_days = DAYS_DEFAULT if self.default_days.blank?
  end
end
```

---

One more thing:

You're testing creating an instance of `ImportFeed` functionality, so you should either pass params to `new` or `create` methods to test it, but you pass an instance of `ImportFeed` to it (from `FactoryGirl`).

According to the docs, `ActiveRecord#new` accepts Hash only (the default argument is `{}` if you don't pass anything).

If you pass an object to it, you'll get `ArgumentError` exception along with "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument" message

```
def assign_attributes(new_attributes)
  if !new_attributes.respond_to?(:stringify_keys)
    raise ArgumentError, "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument."
  end
  return if new_attributes.empty?

  attributes = new_attributes.stringify_keys
  _assign_attributes(sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just using the `initialize` method to change the values according to the conditions:

```
def initialize(params)
  super(params)
  self.enabled = false if self.enabled.blank?
  self.default_radius = DEFAULT_RADIUS  if self.default_radius.blank?
  self.default_days = DAYS_DEFAULT if self.default_days.blank?
end
```

You should not override it (my suggestion) as it may break many things. So instead you may change the values on a callback (`before_validation, before_save, before_create, after_initialize` whichever suits you) like this:

```
before_create :set_default_radius, if: proc { |feed| feed.default_radius.blank? }

def set_default_radius
  self.default_radius = DEFAULT_RADIUS
end
```

And the best way to do this is having the default value in database itself. You can define that in migration:

```
def up
  change_column :import_feeds, :default_radius, :integer, default: 0
end

def down
  change_column :import_feeds, :default_radius, :integer, default: nil
end
```

So if the value is not defined it will always set to the default value mentioned in the migration file.

Also you may have a read of several question related to this which has some very good answers and explanation:

[How to override "new" method for a rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376992/how-to-override-new-method-for-a-rails-model)

[Why is overriding ActiveRecord::Base.initialize wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804868/why-is-overriding-activerecordbase-initialize-wrong)

[Overriding ApplicationRecord initialize, bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165520/overriding-applicationrecord-initialize-bad-idea)

Comment: Thanks, I am having a look at this and will get back.